# How Can i import plugin option?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

hey guys i'm trying to import my plugin option into wordpress with php
but i can't find any tutorial or describe about this section

i have this example:

my option name:

> get_option('meow');

what i have in this option are

```
'cats'=> '2',
'food' => array('tona','fish'),
```

so how can i use

> update_option

to import this values?
i tried this way but it's not working

```
update_option('meow', 'cats','5');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the array as the second argument to [`update_option`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_option/) - WordPress will serialize the value before storing it in the database, and automatically unserialize it when you read it:

```php
update_option( 'meow', array(
    'cats' => '2',
    'food' => array( 'tona', 'fish' ),
) );

$meow = get_option( 'meow' );

print_r( $meow );

// Array
// (
//     [cats] => 2
//     [food] => Array
//         (
//             [0] => tona
//             [1] => fish
//         )
// )
```

Comment: thank you for answer, I tried the code but i have got Error:  `Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in C:\myweb\wp-includes\option.php on line ` and `Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\myweb \wp-includes\option.php on line` AND  `Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\Mywebwp-includes\formatting.php on line  `

Comment: It's worked i just have to check if option exists or not, thanks